# Object Behaviour is different in loop vs repeated execution of jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I have a gymnasium object that passes all the tests and before I tried training on it I wanted to try running to see if it works as expected.

And it does if I instantiate the object in jupyter:

```
kwargs = {'width':10,'length':10,'max_speed':12,'max_volume':200,'back_upper_bound':10,'back_limit':5,
          'ksp':1,'kpv':0.1,'kvl':0.5,'kbp':1,'kds':1,'kss':500,'vid_frequency':1,'max_steps':1000}
    be = gymnasium.make('BasicInfusion-v0',render_mode='rgb_array',**kwargs)
```

And then execute a loop cell repeatedly:

```
j=0
while True:
    t = be.step((1,1))
    j+=1
    if t[2]:
        print('Terminating after {}\n\n'.format(j))
        be.reset()
        break
```

This will out put some random number of steps becuase of some internal randomness

> "Terminating after 10"
> "Terminating after 57"
> "Terminating after 192"
> "Terminating after 45" \

etc

If I run the same loop above but in another loop:

```
`
    for loopv in range(20):
        j=0
        while True:
            t = be.step((1,1))
            j+=1
            if t[2]:
                print('Terminating after {}\n\n'.format(j))
                be.reset()
                break`
```

I get:

> "Terminating after 10"
> "Terminating after 1000"
> "Terminating after 1000"
> "Terminating after 1000"
> "Terminating after 1000"
> "Terminating after 1000"
> "Terminating after 1000"

etc

It also renders videos and it is making videos of different lengths that make sense. (i.e. the 1000 are all the expected length and acting differently) the smaller numbers and step/50 seconds long and also make sense.

Its the same object -  I'm instansiating it exactly once.

There are no def func(var=[]) style errors.

The output is stable and I can go from one cell to the other repeatedly in any order and they will behave the same i.e. 1 loop - random number, 2 loops - random number then 1000 every time.

The only thing I can think of is something to do with the initialisation of the np_random generator interacting in a weird way with jupyter. But that is handled by the gym(nasium) wrapper as far as I am aware.

I'm mystified, I'm really hoping someone can tell me I'm being stupid and point out an obvious error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
be.reset()
```

with:

```
be = gymnasium.make('BasicInfusion-v0',render_mode='rgb_array',**kwargs)
```

It's hard to tell without seeing the code for the gymnasium class, but perhaps the reset method is in some sense not fully resetting your object.

Comment: Thanks. I have not - I did check all the member variables after reset but they appeared identical. I'll give that a try.

Comment: But I'm curious why that wouldn't also effect just mashing the run button on a Jupyter notebook cell multiple times.

Comment: It's mysterious to me as well. You might try writing a minimal program that exhibits this behavior. Can you get it to happen without using your gymnasium class at all?

Comment: The plot thickens - it's a Jupyter thing.

Comment: I took the code into a minimal python file - and added some loops, and copy and pasted the same code a few times to simulate repeatedly executing the same block and it came out at 1000 steps (the maximum I set) every time.

Comment: Excluding the wrapper makes no difference so it is something to do with object permanence in Jupyter - there is no difference in behavior in code and it operates as expected.

Comment: Fascinating! Can you post the (minimal) complete code to demonstrate this effect?